# Remove GLUT function calls

Tags: c, opengl, glut

If I set up a GLUT function call to:

```
glutKeyboardFunc(handleKeys);
```

How can I then remove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass in `NULL`:

```
glutKeyboardFunc(NULL);
```

Comment: Is there a way to assign multiple keyboard functions?